# Return Statement Check Condition

Tags: c++, return

I know this is simple but I am not able to understand how actually it works below is snippet:

```
int test(int a, int b)
{
   return (a==b);
}
```

Return statement is returning 1 in case of match and else 0.
a) What exactly happening here ?
b) So Is this a better idea to use this when we simply want to compare and return rather then using if and else ?

Comment: Since others have already answered *how* this code works, I want to add that, in this situation, it is better to change the return type of `test()` `bool`, IMO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`a== b`  .. if it is true it evaluates to `true`, if it isn't it evaluates to `false`. It returns a copy of the evaluation as `int`, the magic is done by the equality operator.

It is perfectly acceptable to use it. Easy to read as well.

`return a == b` is just a nicer way of saying:

```
 if(a==b)
    return true;  
 else
   return false; //1 or 0  as true or false depending on the language.
```

Comment: so only with return It can be used or there are any other example as well..means other than (if,else,while...)

Comment: @Himank Sorry, not sure if I understand your question.. updated the answer though.

Comment: I don't think there's anything technically stopping you from using it anywhere else; it will return a 1 for true and 0 for false. I can't think of any reason why you couldn't do a = a+(a==a), for example, to increment a (except that it is awful to read)

Comment: @JanGorzny As this is C++ that'd be valid. However, strictly typed languages will refuse to compile: `a=a+(true)` for example.

Comment: @Himank: It's the conversion of a boolean to an integer that causes a `true` to become a `1` and a `false` to become a `0`. In this case, `return` causes that conversion because the function returns an `int`. But you can force that conversion other ways too. For example `int j = (a == b);` or `static_cast<int>(a == b)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a boolean statement that is returning true or false based on the values of a and b.  This boolean is getting cast into an int as this is the return type of the function.

This is probably a trivial example, but I would suggest that if the function "test" is truly a boolean, then it should return bool type and not an integer.  Typically if you're returning an int, then you would return:

- -1 if a < b
- 0 if a == b
- 1 if a > b

Comment: One more doubt...like return statement acting here as an If statement so are there any other build in examples as well where we can use (a==b) for the check ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Yes, this function is essentially the same as an if statement with a name.  The main thing to take from this is that you have a statement that generates a boolean response which is then being cast into an integer type.

Comment: You can use (a == b) outside of if and return.  You could just do bool y = (a == b).  Another place this type of syntax shows is in the ternary operator, in the sense of   int z = (a ==b) ? 20 : 40;  This states that IF a == b THEN assign z the value of 20 ELSE assign z 40.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have the if statement in the return statement. What's happening is that when `a==b` in a `if` statement, it returns true, the number `1`. And if it's false, it returns `0`. This is the exact same thing happening here.

Your code can be rewritten to be more clear sort of like this:

```
int test(int a, int b){
   if(a==b)
       return 1;
   else
       return 0;
}
```

As for practicality or best practice, I would say it's up to you, both accomplish the same thing, but your way is just slightly more concise.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly happening here ?

```
if(a == b)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
```

> So Is this a better idea to use this when we simply want to compare and return rather then using if and else ?

They're equivalents. No one is better than another. It's just coding style / better look.

Answer (score 0):

The "==" between a and b is acting as an operator that checks if a equals b.  This returns true (or as an int, 1) if they are, and false (0) if they are not.

As far as I know, this looks neater than the equivalent if-statement, but I'm not sure it's any better or worse (pending compiler optimizations)

Answer (score 0):

a == b is a expression which return true of false, a bool type, as the return type is int, the   evaluation value will be converted implicitly to int before the calling is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The expression (a == b) is of type bool, which can be implicitly converted into an int: false is converted to 0, and true is converted to 1. So basically it is equivalent to "if (a == b) return 1; else return 0;", just more compact. Sorry for bad formatting, i am typing from a mobile

Answer (score 0):

if statement is different from the single boolean expression. As in the if statement, compiler will generate JUMP instruction which can harm branch prediction, thus hampering program performance perhaps.

As in a == b expression, the clever compiler may generate xor instruction instead of using  JUMP, it's more efficient, and more readable for programmer(not human:))